# Pact Provider @State Test always returning 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pact, pact-jvm

I am able to get a test running for a Spring Boot Project but I'm always getting a 404 on the @State test.

```
@TargetRequestFilter
public void exampleRequestFilter(HttpRequest request) {
  System.out.println(request.toString());
  request.addHeader("Authorization", JIMMY_CARTER_TOKEN);
}

@BeforeClass
public static void setupApplication() {
  SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(App.class);
  application.setAdditionalProfiles("integration");
  application.run("--server.port=9000");
}

@TestTarget
public final HttpTarget target = new HttpTarget("http", "127.0.0.1", 9000);

@State("user id") // Method will be run before testing interactions that require "default" or "no-data" state
public void toUserId() {
    System.out.println("Test User Id");
}
```

What's strange is I can tell it's hitting the right endpoint by printing out the request information and the Authorization header. I put a debug statement in and verified that I can call with the same credentials and endpoint as the test. However the test is always failing with a 404. Is there something I'm missing in my setup?

```
"request": {
            "method": "GET",
            "path": "/api/user/XXXXXX"
        },
        "response": {
            "status": 200,
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/vnd.api+json;charset=UTF-8"
            },
            "body": ... 
},
        "providerStates": [
            {
                "name": "user id"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what requests are being made by enabling debug logging with the Apache HTTP Client and the pact-jvm libraries. For Apache HTTP Client, please refer to https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html.

For an example of what the debug logs you are looking for, this is from the example `ContractTest` from pact-jvm (https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/blob/master/pact-jvm-provider-junit/src/test/java/au/com/dius/pact/provider/junit/ContractTest.java):

```
    13:09:20.012 [Test worker] DEBUG au.com.dius.pact.provider.ProviderClient - Making request for provider au.com.dius.pact.provider.ProviderInfo(http, localhost, 8332, /, myAwesomeService, null, null, au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.target.HttpTarget$$Lambda$14/771479970@1dec1536, null, null, false, null, changeit, null, true, false, true, null, [], []):
    13:09:20.018 [Test worker] DEBUG au.com.dius.pact.provider.ProviderClient -     method: GET
          path: /data
          query: [:]
          headers: [:]
          matchers: MatchingRules(rules=[:])
          generators: Generators(categories={})
          body: OptionalBody(state=MISSING, value=null)
        13:09:20.475 [Test worker] INFO au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.ContractTest - exampleRequestFilter called: GET http://localhost:8332/data HTTP/1.1
    13:09:20.537 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> GET /data HTTP/1.1
    13:09:20.538 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: localhost:8332
    13:09:20.538 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
    13:09:20.551 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_131)
    13:09:20.553 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    13:09:20.553 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "GET /data HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
    13:09:20.554 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: localhost:8332[\r][\n]"
    13:09:20.555 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
    13:09:20.558 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_131)[\r][\n]"
    13:09:20.559 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
    13:09:20.560 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
    13:09:20.774 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 204 No Content[\r][\n]"
    13:09:20.775 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Sat, 23 Sep 2017 03:09:20 GMT[\r][\n]"
    13:09:20.775 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: rest-client-driver(1.1.45)[\r][\n]"
    13:09:20.779 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
    13:09:20.784 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
    13:09:20.785 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Sat, 23 Sep 2017 03:09:20 GMT
    13:09:20.785 [Test worker] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Server: rest-client-driver(1.1.45)
    13:09:20.842 [Test worker] DEBUG au.com.dius.pact.provider.ProviderClient - Received response: HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
    13:09:20.867 [Test worker] DEBUG au.com.dius.pact.provider.ProviderClient - Response: [statusCode:204, headers:[Date:Sat, 23 Sep 2017 03:09:20 GMT, Server:rest-client-driver(1.1.45)]]
    13:09:21.724 [Test worker] DEBUG au.com.dius.pact.model.Matching$ - Found a matcher for text/plain -> Some((text/plain,au.com.dius.pact.matchers.PlainTextBodyMatcher@29c3e77b))
        returns a response which
          has status code 204 (OK)
          has a matching body (OK)
```

Comment: I also found this that helps Spring Boot capture all incoming and outgoing requests. https://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2015/07/01/spring-framework-hidden-gems/ I'm still struggling trying to find out why I'm getting a 404 and trying to figure out why internal tests are failing why external calls are working fine.

Comment: @JoelHolmes did you ever find out why it returned 404?

Comment: Well, even the link to the `ContractTest.java` source returns a 404 now